# User can choose two different math formulas with if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, console-application

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcOne()
{
    cout << "one";
}

void funcTwo()
{
    cout << "two";
}

int main()
{
    int vienadojums;

    cout << "Type [K] or [L]: ";
    cin >> output;
    
    if (output == 'K' || 'k')
    {
        funcOne();
    }
    else if (output == 'L' || 'l')
    {
         funcTwo();
    };

    


    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't matter what input I enter, it will always output `funcOne()`. With this code, I want to make, so user can choose 2 different math problem formulas by inputting [K] or [L]. But for some reason no matter what you enter it will show `funcOne()`

Comment: How about `if (output == 'K' || output == 'k')`, etc.?

Comment: please post the actual code. The code you posted cannot compile as `output` is not declared.

Comment: A few more cases and you'll benefit from `cin >> output; output = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(output))`. Now you only need one test for each letter, the lower case version.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (output == 'K' || 'k')
```

This is true if:

- `output` equals `'K'`

or

- `'k'` (is not equal zero)

The second condition always evaluates to true.

What you *want* is:

```
if ( ( output == 'K' ) || ( output == 'k' ) )
```

Same for the second condition.

---

I assume an edit artifact here:

```
int vienadojums;

cout << "Type [K] or [L]: ";
cin >> output;
```

You never defined `output`, and you never used `vienadojums`. If those were meant to be the same variable, you would be expecting an `int` from input, not a `char` (as you assume later on in your code). This error is covered up by your first condition always evaluating to `true` regardless of what the user enters, but you will have to fix this as well.

(Sidenote, when you *are* reading `int` from user input, check `cin.fail()` in case the user did *not* enter digits. Same for C and `scanf()`, *check* that return value.)

---

The meta to take away here: *Always* put paranthesis around subexpressions, and enable compiler warnings at the strictest level possible; only by telling the compiler *explicitly* what you want do you give the compiler the opportunity to tell you where you might have erred. The compiler could, and should, have warned you of all of the above.

Comment: Fixing the `output`/`vienadojums` thing, I get no warnings on the OP's code using `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. And how would adding extra parentheses help in this case?

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/PGcdGcKaj

Comment: ((Redundant parentheses) make things (harder (to read))).

Comment: @FredLarson: `-Wall` means "all those that are really easy to fix", and `-Wextra` means "some more". I am not kidding, that is what the manual says. There is a *lot* more. Adding the parenthesis would have given either `( ( output == 'K' ) || 'k' )` or `( output == ( 'K' || 'k' ) )`, both (hopefully) showing that there is something off. You are right that neither variant triggers a warning with current GCC, which is rather disappointing. Still, either recommendation is beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement the condition is always true because:

> `[x] or true => true`

> `[x] => (output == 'K')`

> `'k'` is a truthy value

no matter the result of `output == 'K'`

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a character literal (for example, `'k'`) will contextually convert to a boolean expression, where true is any non-null value (i.e. the value is not the null character `'\0'`†), and false is the null value. This happens in any context where a boolean expression is expected by the compiler like, naturally, the clause of an if-statement.

So when you write `if (output == 'K' || 'k')`, the character literal on the right is contextually converted to a boolean value, and this expression is logically equivalent to `if (output == 'K' || true)`, which will always evaluate to `true`.

The correct way to write this is `if (output == 'K' || output == 'k')`.

<sup>† This is the null character, `'\0'`, and NOT the character literal `'0'`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `vienadojums` as having the type char

```
char vienadojums;
```

and use it instead of the variable `output` because in the if statement you are comparing it with characters.

Or instead of the declaration of the variable `vienadojums`

```
char vienadojums;
```

decalre

```
char output;
```

And change the conditions in the if statements like

```
if (output == 'K' || output == 'k')
{
    funcOne();
}
else if (output == 'L' || output == 'l')
{
     funcTwo();
};
```

Otherwise for example this if statement

```
 if (output == 'K' || 'k')
```

always evaluates to true independent on the value stored in the variable `output` because the character literal `'k'` is not equal to `0`.

That is the above if statement is equivalent to

```
if ( ( output == 'K' ) || ( 'k' != 0 ) )
```

Pay attention to that in general when you have many functions from which you need to select one function to call the approach with if statements is not flexible.

Instead you could store all functions and corresponding identifiers of the functions in a container for example in an array. And then select a required function from the container according to the user input.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void funcOne()
{
    std::cout << "one\n";
}

void funcTwo()
{
    std::cout << "two\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<char, void( * )( void )> expressions[] =
    {
        { 'l', funcOne }, { 'k', funcTwo }
    };

    std::cout << "Type any of ";

    bool following = false;

    for (auto &[selection, func] : expressions)
    {
        if (following)
        {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << '\'' << selection << '\'';
        following = true;
    }
    std::cout << " : ";

    char selection = '\0';

    std::cin >> selection;

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( expressions ), std::end( expressions ),
        [&]( const auto &item ) 
        { 
            return item.first == ::tolower( ( unsigned char )selection ); 
        } );

    if (it != std::end( expressions ))
    {
        it->second();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
    }
}
```

The program output might look like for example

```
Type any of 'l', 'k' : L
one
```